# How to batch execute .Rmd files from the command line and save the output to the same .Rmd files

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have several dozens of `.Rmd` files that I want to execute programmatically from the CLI and save the output to the same files. Imagine that these are template analysis files that I want to populate with the various outputs and share these templates then with others in this executed state as runnable `.Rmd` files.

By *execute* I mean `Run All Cells` like I can do in RStudio.

How can I do that?

As far as I can see knitting doesn't solve my problem because `.Rmd` doesn't seem to be a viable output format. Rendering from the CLI just renders the file but doesn't save the outputs to the file itself.

I am working on macOs and have R available in a conda enviroment.

Thanks in advance for your help or any pointers in the right direction!

**Example**

A very much simplified version of my template looks like this:

````
---
title: "Sample doc"
output: html_document
date: "2023-01-02"
---

# Data analysis template for dataset 001

## Load packages
```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(skimr)
```

## Load data
```{r}
# the dataset will change from template to template
df <- read.csv2("sample_dataset_001.csv")
```

## Analyze data
```{r}
# recipients should see output of e.g. skim, ggplot, summaries etc.
skim(df)
```

## Recipients will code from here
```{r}
# recipients will continue with their own code here
print()
```
````

- I generate these templates programmatically and insert metadata about the datasets and the respective data set links into these files.
- I then want to execute these, so that recipients can see immediately the outputs, without executing the .Rmd files themselves.
- Then they should be able to open the .Rmd files in RStudio and continue to work on the analysis.

Comment: Why not generate HTML or PDF outputs with `rmarkdown::render` and circulate those formats?

Comment: I want to stick with the .Rmd format because recipients can immediately work with these files and continue the data analysis. This wouldn't be possible with HTML or PDF.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. If I get it right, you have a template that uses parameters, e.g `city`, which is called in a script in the Rmd file with `params$city`. Then you want to call `render()` with different values for this `city` parameter and produce a list of Rmd files that can be run by other people. Is this correct? Otherwise, can you clarify? Either way, it would be helpful to include a small example of what you want to do.

Comment: @bretauv Thanks for your comment. I have provided a minimal example. To your question: I don't use R parameters like you mentioned but rather do the parametrization programmatically by text editing the templates. The templates I can produce. Unfortunately I haven't found a way yet to execute these programmatically so that the outputs are shown in the `.Rmd` files. I have too many files to execute these by hand and need to automate.

Comment: @petezurich What do you mean by “execute”? Do you want to render the Rmd files or not? Saving the rendered output to Rmd doesn’t really make sense, and overriding the input file is a strikingly bad idea in general. But it‘s possible if you really want it, since Markdown files are valid RMarkdown files so you can just knit the files and rename them.

Comment: @KonradRudolph By *execute* I mean `Run All Cells`, like I do in RStudio. Sorry if I wasn't able to express this clearer in my question (just edited to reflect that...). I can only knit to `.md` files but not `.Rmd` files as far as I understand. I tried to rename these to `.Rmd` but this doesn't help since the file then does not properly execute in RStudio.

Comment: In that case you can run `knitr::knit()` on your file via the command line (i.e. `Rscript -e 'knitr::knit("inputfile.rmd")'` to achieve much the same effect.

Comment: Hmm. Actually if I understand you correctly that's not quite what you want, since you want the rendered *R notebook*, not just the Rmd/Markdown file. Unfortunately that won't be as easy, since running the cells in RStudio does not store the output in the Rmd file, it stores them extraneously inside a hidden directory in your home directory, and the format is non-portable. Ultimately using `knitr::knit` is probably still the way to go.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I tried the command you suggested. This results in an `.md` file rather than a `.Rmd`. Printout from CLI: `output file: test_file.md`. Even if I rename this it isn't executable in Rstudio anymore. How can I knit so that I keep the Rmd or Notebook?

Comment: @petezurich Yes, like I said, you will need to rename the file. And as the subsequent comment mentions it isn't quite the same because RStudio R Notebooks are non-portable. But you can trivially make the code blocks executable again by replacing occurrences of \`\`\`r with \`\`\`{r} (e.g., using the command line, `sed 's/^###r/###{r}/' file.md > file.rmd` — replace `#` by backticks (changed here to work around comment formatting limitations).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Ok, I see. Thanks for the suggestion! I will try this. I was wondering if there is a – let's say – proper way of doing it without messing with file formats and best practices. But again – thanks very much for your help! I very much appreciate that.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks too for your command line for editing and renaming the file! Awesome! 